# jquery ajax cache false not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

I am using jquery ajax get method.

```
$.ajax({
url : 'url',
type : 'get',
cache : false,
data : {'timestamp' : '<?php echo time();?>'},
beforeSend : function()
{

},
success :function()
{

}

});
```

ajax cache:flase is not seem not work.I don't know what is wrong.
when a visitor click an image, will be appear image thumbnails lists.
and when each thumbnails click ,will be appear big image,But it not work.
My english is bad.please check website url.Someone please help me.

[Website Link](http://www.modulararchitectsmm.com/residential)

Comment: You need to show the surrounding code. `cache: false` just adds a pseudo-random key to the URL so the server thinks it is a new request and will not cache it. Use a Network tool to view the requests (Fiddler2 or the Chrome F12 tools).

Comment: Note: You need to fade out the existing image before inserting the new one as you keep seeing flashes of the previous image.

Comment: I alread add timestamp with php,I will edit my question.

Comment: look at what kind of caching is used... whether a modified since/etag based cache is used

Answer (score 0):

Placing this at the top of my ajax.js worked for me

```
$.ajaxSetup( { cache : false } )
```